SwiftData crashes at init
Below is the minimum code that causes the crash.
What I want to achieve: pass a default AchievementB to the view and then change (based on user input) and insert into achievements.
update: after a few attempts, it seems that i can't init the object before the view is appear, but i don't know why.
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
class AchievementB: Identifiable {
  let id: UUID = UUID()

  init(id: UUID = UUID()) {
      self.id = id
  }
}

struct AchievementView: View {
  @State var options: AchievementB

  @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
  @Query var achievements: [AchievementB]
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("hello")
  }
}

#Preview {
  AchievementView(options: AchievementB())
    .modelContainer(for: AchievementB.self)
}


So you are running this in Xcode Previews?

that is correct

It doesn't crash for me. Did you set up the ModelContainer properly for the app itself?

that's all the code i have. what kind of setup are you referring to?

In your app code in .swift you must also add a .modelContainer modifier to the WindowGroup

for that i do have it: WindowGroup {
AchievementView(options: AchievementB())
}
.modelContainer(for: [AchievementB.self])

Maybe you just need to clean your build folder or something because on iOS 17.5 (Xcode 15.4) your code works fine as is on my computer.

In your code, the AchievementB object is created before a model container exists. AchievementB() is executed first, before the .modelContainer(for: ...) modifier, which creates the model container.
Before you create any @Model objects, you should first create a model container, because the @Model objects needs a model container for their properties to work. When you get/set a property of a @Model object, the actual reading and writing of the data is delegated to the model container.
You should manually create a ModelContainer first, then add it to the view using the other overload of the modelContainer modifier.
#Preview {
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: AchievementB.self, configurations: config)
    return AchievementView(options: AchievementB())
        .modelContainer(container)
}

Note that you need to explicitly return because #Preview is not a view builder.
Side note: options should not be a @State if you are going to pass things to it. It should just be a regular let/var, or @Bindable if you want to get Bindings out of it.

With Xcode 15.4 this doesn't seem to be needed and having only AchievementView(options: AchievementB()).modelContainer(for: AchievementB.self, inMemory: true) in the #Preview macro works fine.

@JoakimDanielson Ah that's interesting. I (and probably the OP too) am on Xcode 15.3.
